# In wso2 esb after enabling DSS feature it moves the dss service as faulty service

Tags: wso2, wso2-data-services-server, apache-synapse, wso2-esb

I have enabled the dss feature in wso2 esb and tried to deploy the sample dss file in esb it makes the dss service as faulty service . I have enabled http,https and vfs transports in axis2.how to resolve it ?

`<data name="XML_DataService" serviceNamespace="http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice">
    <config id="default">
        <property name="driverClassName">net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver</property>
        <property name="url">jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://localhost:1433;databaseName=INTEGDB</property>
        <property name="username">admin</property>
        <property name="password">password12$</property>
        <property name="minIdle">1</property>
        <property name="maxActive">10</property>
    </config>
    <query id="select_all_XML_DATA_query" useConfig="default">
        <sql>Select XML_FILENAME,XML_TOUCHPOINT,XML_PROCESS from INTG_JLOG_XML_TBL</sql>
        <result element="XML_DATACollection" rowName="XML_DATA">
            <element column="XML_FILENAME" name="XML_FILENAME" xsdType="string"/>
            <element column="XML_TOUCHPOINT" name="XML_TOUCHPOINT" xsdType="xs:string"/>
            <element column="XML_PROCESS" name="XML_PROCESS" xsdType="xs:string"/>
        </result>
    </query>
    <operation name="select_all_XML_DATA_query">
        <call-query href="select_all_XML_DATA_query"/>
    </operation>
</data>`

Comment: What is the data service you are trying to add? There should be an issue with your data service. Did you check your database connection configuration?

Comment: i have added my dbs file . i have added the jtds jar in lib folder also .

Comment: When VFS enabled in wso2 esb, DSS services will indicate as a faulty service. Why do not you try with the different server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create an XML file with the name, {dataservicename}_services.xml (In your case, XML_DataService_services.xml) and add the following content.

```
<serviceGroup>
    <service name="XML_DataService">            
    <Description>test</Description>     
    <transports>
        <transport>https</transport>
        <transport>http</transport>
    </transports>
    </service>
</serviceGroup>
```

Copy this file into the same location that the corresponding .dbs file deployed. ($CARBON_HOME/repository/deployment/server/dataservices)

Then the dataservice will only be exposed to transports specified in the services.xml file. However the proper solution will be introduced from the DSS 3.2.2 release. You can download the Alpha release from [here](https://svn.wso2.org/repos/wso2/scratch/chunk13-release/14-09-2014/wso2dss-3.2.2.zip).